# Python hoisting?

Tags: python

When do objects get created in Python? Do they get created when interpreting the variable declaration line or are they created at the start of the execution?

Comment: Even in Javascript, the language where hoisting is a thing, there's no such thing as "memory hoisting". Where did you get the idea "memory hoisting" is a thing that exists?

Comment: Thanks @ruturaj, so if I write a line 120 as x=12, the object 12 will be created at the time of interpreting line 120 right??  not at the beginning of the program..

Comment: @hkonala correct. the `int` `12` is created, then the name `x` is bound to it in whatever namespace/scope that statement is written

Comment: Correct if you are using pure interpretation in the case of cpython

Comment: There's some other complexity around that in that some objects are "interned" and may already exist in memory: http://guilload.com/python-string-interning/#comment-3075560497

Comment: Seems like pointers in python. Thanks @MatthewSchinckel. To me this is something new.

Answer (score 3):

Objects are created when encountered in the Python script. **Nothing in Python is hoisted**, not variables, not functions, nothing.

So this does not work:

```py
print(foo())  # NameError: name 'foo' is not defined

def foo():
    return 'hello'
```

While this does:

```py
def foo():
    return 'hello'

print(foo())  # 'hello'
```